# Create Paired images by "Near" date

Tags: google-earth-engine, layer-name

I have code the retrieve images from sentinel 1 and sentinel 2, calcultes NDVI for sentinel 2 and then pair manually two images that I choose according to their dates.

My qiestion is if there is any way I can tell GEE to pair images automaticlly by the date, meaning, if it finds similar date in the 2 imagecollection, pair them into 2 bands images, and more advanced- if not, pair image that is 2-3 days "distance" from each other .
Is something like that is possible?

This is  my code right now which do that manually.

*I can't share the shape but I can say that any polygon in north of Thailand will give you the same results.

```
//Filter the collection for the VH product from the descending track

//var geometry=MITR;
var Sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
        .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
        .select('VH')
        .filterDate('2019-01-01','2019-11-12')
        .filterBounds(geometry);

var clippedVH= Sentinel1.map(function(im){ 
  return im.clip(geometry);
}); 

var filterSpeckles = function(img) {
  var vh = img.select('VH') ;//select the VH polarization band
  var VH_smoothed = vh.focal_median(40,'circle','meters').clip(geometry).rename('VH_Filtered'); //Apply a focal median filter
  return img.addBands(VH_smoothed); // Add filtered VH band to original image
};

var Clipped_Speckles = clippedVH.map(filterSpeckles);
//print(Clipped_Speckles);

//check that speckle filter worked
var list_before=clippedVH.toList(clippedVH.size());
var list_after=Clipped_Speckles.toList(Clipped_Speckles.size());


var before=ee.Image(list_before.get(1));
var after=ee.Image(list_after.get(1)).clip(geometry).select('VH_Filtered');



Map.addLayer(before,{min: -30, max: 1},'Before');
Map.addLayer(after,{bands: 'VH_Filtered',min: -30, max: 1},'after');




var clippedVHsize=Clipped_Speckles.size();
print('SAR images data:',Clipped_Speckles);

var listOfImagesSAR =(Clipped_Speckles.toList(Clipped_Speckles.size()));

var NumberOfImagesSAR=listOfImagesSAR.size();


var listOfNumbersSAR = ee.List.sequence(0, NumberOfImagesSAR.subtract(2));
listOfNumbersSAR = listOfNumbersSAR.map(function(n) {
  return ee.Number(n).add(1);
});
print(typeof(listOfNumbersSAR));
listOfNumbersSAR=listOfNumbersSAR.getInfo();




for (var i in listOfNumbersSAR) {
  var image = ee.Image(listOfImagesSAR.get(listOfNumbersSAR[i]));
  var toexport=image.visualize({min: -30, max: 1}).addBands(image);


  //do what ever you need with image
  //Map.addLayer(image,{bands: 'VH_Filtered',min: -30, max: 1},'SAR'+ i);
//   // Export.image.toDrive({
//   // image: toexport.toFloat(),
//   // description: i,
//   // scale:10,
//   // crs:'EPSG:4326',
//   // maxPixels:1310361348,
//   // region:geometry.geometry().bounds()

// // });


}


print(ui.Chart.image.series(filterNDVI, geometry, ee.Reducer.mean(), 20));
print(ui.Chart.image.series(clippedVH, geometry, ee.Reducer.mean(), 10));

//select the images for scatter plot
//select NDVI
var imageNDVIcor=ee.Image(listOfImages.get(11));
//select SAR image
var imageSARcor=ee.Image(listOfImagesSAR.get(24));
var imageSAR1=imageSARcor.select('VH_Filtered');


print(imageSAR1);



//Get information about the  projection.
var sar1Projection =  imageSAR1.projection();
print('SAR projection:', sar1Projection);

var NDVIProjection =  imageNDVIcor.projection();
print('NDVI projection:',  NDVIProjection);

// //resample SAR image to NDVI image

var SARreproject=imageSAR1.reduceResolution({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean()}).reproject({crs: NDVIProjection});

Map.addLayer(SARreproject,{min: -30, max: 1},'Reproject SAR_18_03_2019');
Map.addLayer(imageNDVIcor,NDVIcolor,'NDVI18_03_2019');

//print(SARreproject);



// make an image for the two variables
var pairedImage =  ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([imageNDVIcor,SARreproject]).toBands().rename(["NDVI","SAR"]);
print("pairedImage",pairedImage);
// Generate a sample of points within the region
var sample = pairedImage.sampleRegions(geometry, null,30);
// print("sample",sample);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use joins for this.

The below solution joins an S1 and S2 collection together. Each S2 scene will have a list of S1 scenes, where each S1 scene is within 16 days of the corresponding S2 scene, and intersects it.

Since a single S1 scene might not cover a whole S2 scene, a quality mosaic of the S1 scenes is created, using the pixels closest to the S2 scene date.

```
var withinSixteenDays = ee.Filter.maxDifference({
  difference: 16 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
})
var intersects = ee.Filter.intersects({
  leftField: '.geo',
  rightField: '.geo',
  maxError: 10
})
var s1s2 = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.Join.saveAll({matchesKey: 's1'})
    .apply({ 
      primary: s2, 
      secondary: s1, 
      condition: ee.Filter.and(withinSixteenDays, intersects)
    })
  )
  .map(function (s2) {
    var s1 = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
        ee.List(s2.get('s1'))
      )
      .map(function (s1) {
        var quality = ee.Image( // -(number of days from the s2 image)
            s1.date()
              .difference(s2.date(), 'day')
              .abs()
              .multiply(-1)
          )
          .rename('quality')
        return s1
          .addBands(quality)
          .float()
          .updateMask(s2.mask())
      })
      .qualityMosaic('quality') 
      .select('VH')
    return s2.addBands(s1)
  })
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e6b0fcc0a5952d94ea470e7cf6b079ec

Comment: This is great, could you please just elaborate about the MaxDifference: why do you do this? and what is th emeaning of the line :difference: 16*24*60.....

Comment: "difference" is the maximum difference between time_start of S1 and S2 - 16 days in milliseconds. The intersects filter ensures the S1 and S2 scenes intersect. ".geo" is the geometry/footprint of each scene. The final result, s1s2, is an image with two band, NDVI and VH. NDVI comes from a single S2 scene, while VH is a mosaic from the scenes closest in time to that S2 scene.